# Convert AccountExpirationDate into a compareable Datetype

Tags: powershell

i tried to create a tool for my company to send an email to our IT when a user account is expired.

This part works fine so far.

But we have an issue. Sometimes we change the expiration date of the accounts. The problem is that i saved the names into a txt file because we run that script every night to check for new expired accounts. If that txt wouldn´t exist, then we would get hundrets of emails every day.

I tried multiple convert things like "[Datetime] $UserAccountsExpiredDate -ge $TodaysDate" But there is always an error message like this:

```
"@{AccountExpirationDate=13.11.2022 00:00:00}" vom Typ "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" kann nicht in den Typ "System.DateTime" konvertiert 
werden."
In C:\Scripte\AbgelaufeneUserSkript\Abfrage_abgelaufene_User_NicoTest_Teiltest.ps1:38 Zeichen:9
+      if(([Datetime] $userAccountExpiredDate -ge $TodaysDate))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastConstructorException
```

I know that many of you cant speak german. The AccountExpirationDate can´t be converted into System-Datetime.

I couldn´t find any solution, so im here right now. My original code is below this:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, department | ? {($_.AccountExpirationDate -NE $NULL -AND $_.AccountExpirationDate -LT (Get-Date)) }
$TxtPath = "C:\scripte\AbgelaufeneUserSkript\Abgelaufene_Benutzer.txt"
$UserDeactivated = Get-Content $TxtPath
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).ToString()




if(Test-Path $TxtPath)
{

}
else
{
    New-Item $TxtPath
}

echo $TodaysDate


foreach($userintxt in Get-Content $TxtPath)
{
    Write-Host $userintxt
    $userAccountExpiredDate = (Get-ADUser $userintxt -Properties AccountExpirationDate) | Select-Object AccountExpirationDate


    Write-Host $userAccountExpiredDate
    echo $userintxt.Name
     if(($userAccountExpiredDate -ge $TodaysDate))
    {
        Write-Host $userintxt.Name "This account is no more expired"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $userintxt.Name "This account is still expired"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `AccountExpirationDate` is already a DateTime object (LDAP property `accountExpires`, converted to local time), you can compare it to another DateTime object directly.

Therefore, set `$TodaysDate` to a real DateTime object:

```
# do not stringify it, but instead take the date as DateTime object set to midnight
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).Date
```

Then your code only needs to Expand property AccountExpirationDate using

```
$userAccountExpiredDate = (Get-ADUser $userintxt -Properties AccountExpirationDate).AccountExpirationDate
```

or

```
$userAccountExpiredDate = Get-ADUser $userintxt -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AccountExpirationDate
```

After that,

```
if ($userAccountExpiredDate -ge $TodaysDate) {..}
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[Datetime]::ParseExact` to convert the string to a date time:

if for example your string date format is: `13.11.2022 00:00:00`

You Can Parse it like this:

```
$Date = [datetime]::ParseExact("13.11.2022 00:00:00","dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)
```

Change the format as needed, see more information: [Date Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)